# Getting the html generated by posting some specific values in form

Tags: php, html, curl

How I can get the HTML that is generated in the result of posting some form fields? I want to make it dynamic. For example: for each value in my drop down, I want to get the HTML using `cURL`. Is it possible to send some parameters along with the `cURL` requests?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question would be much easier to answer if you provide some of your source code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,        "http://duckduckgo.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,       TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "q=val");

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

print($result);
?>
```

See more about it here: http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post